# You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first

Tags: installation, hacked

My website was crashed by hackers and i am trying to restore from my backup.
i have deleted all old files and trying to restore from the backup. i copied all my WP files in public_html. after restoration of database it's throwing  an error"You appear to have already installed WordPress.To reinstall please clear your old database table first". I am newbie to WordPress. could someone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open `wp-config.php` (which is in your new WordPress installation's main directory) in a text editor.
Locate the line that reads `$table_prefix = 'wp_';`
Modify the value of `$table_prefix` to the prefix in your backup database and Save. Refresh the setup page of your WordPress installation.

Comment: Table prefix was already updated. but the throwing same error. please guide me to fix it.

Comment: Try to create a new `wp-config.php` file

Comment: created new wp-config.php. but still same error.

Comment: I think you need to do a fresh install of wordpress and then add your theme and drop old database and then create new database add it to `wp-config.php` then import backed-up database and change `table_prefix`.